# How to set the XCode FILEHEADER macro when using Swift PM?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, command-line-tool

I am working on a Swift package command line tool that has a third-party dependency. It has been working great just opening the repo folder and using SwiftPM, except that I don't seem to have control over the default file header. In other projects that have used an .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace, I was able to control this using the steps outlined here:

https://medium.com/@silmy/how-to-easily-change-your-file-header-text-in-xcode-347fa77d76f4

Putting the Plist in the Xcode data directory isn't what I want since the header could be different for different projects, and in any event I want to commit it to the repo so anyone who might contribute files to the project will use the same header.

We have tried simply creating an Xcodeproj or Xcworkspace using CocoaPods or Carthage, and have run into extremely frustrating issues. CocoaPods says that command line tools can't use third party dependencies, which seems untrue since it works fine when running purely in SwiftPM, and Carthage just completely fails to run correctly on my machine.

Does anyone know a way to set the default file header using SwiftPM in a way that can be committed to the repo and not require other dependency managers?